# @ManyToMany mapping doesn't update the corresponding Tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

My `Course` class

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Column
    @Id
    private String courseCode;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "Students_RegisteredCourse",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "courseCode")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "email")}
    )
    private Set<Student> registeredStudents = new HashSet<>();


..
..
..
}
```

My `Students` class

```
@Entity
public class Student extends User {
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "registeredStudents")
private List<Course> registeredCourse = new ArrayList<>();
...
}
```

The `user` class is a usually Entity.

I'm trying to add courses to registeredCourses while creating new Students. But it is not working out. `Course.getCourseByName("Discrete Mathematics")` works fine. No new rows are added to `Students_RegisteredCourse` table on successfully executing this code.

```
    session.beginTransaction();

    Student temp = new Student();
    temp.setName("Siddharth Yadav");
    temp.setEmail("siddharth16268@iiitd.ac.in");
    temp.setRollNumber("2016268");
    temp.setPassword("[{Sid@123}]");

    List<Course> cse = new ArrayList<>();
    cse.add(Course.getCourseByName("Discrete Mathematics"));
    cse.add(Course.getCourseByName("Advanced Programming"));
    temp.setRegisteredCourse(cse);

    session.update(temp);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

`

Comment: maybe you need to add cascade  type also to  Student entity that way you can update your courses. cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST or did you try to use session merge or session save ? just given idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that each of the Courses also has the registeredStudents filled with the new student:

```
List<Course> cse = new ArrayList<>();
cse.add(Course.getCourseByName("Discrete Mathematics"));
cse.add(Course.getCourseByName("Advanced Programming"));
temp.setRegisteredCourse(cse);

for(Course course: cse){
    cse.getRegisteredStudents().add(temp);
}
```

Now the persistence provider will know that there is the mutual manytomany dependency here and perform an insert to the link table.

Also as the Student is created anew here .. you should use persist instead of update:

```
session.persist(temp);
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to avoid doing addition twice?